# How to implement a modal inside a component but not whole page

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

modal popup should appear inside of the div with React hooks but not jQuery
[image: Sample example of modal popup]

I tried React-bootstrap but the modal is applying for whole page

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question as you posted is unanswerable. Check out ["How to ask a question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [provide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you tried and how is your code structured? What's your intention and how is it not accomplished? Without further context and code samples, the community won't be able to help any further.